# Which software can I use to animate my Blender models for Unity?

Tags: animation, unity

I'm unsure whether this question is appropriate here, but I really need help.

I've made a bunch of rigged models with Blender which have to be imported to Unity.

What I'm wondering is, which software (including Blender) can I use to animate my models which can then be imported to Unity without much trouble? I've done some research online and what I usually see is that Blender might not be the best solution.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html

Comment: Can't believe I didn't find that, thank you!